# bitbucketでbranchを削除出来ないようにするには

Tags: git, bitbucket

bitbucketではmaster branchが削除出来ないようになっていますが、他のbranchでも消えてほしくないものがあったりします。
そういう場合の設定は用意されているのでしょうか。

また、gitレベルでbranchの削除をプロテクトする機能はありますか。

Answer (score -1):

別のユーザを作成し、[Using branch permissions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-branch-permissions-776639807.html) を参考に  prevent deletion で保護したいブランチを選択してください。